# Semantic UI popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, semantic-ui

I've looked all over the [Semantic UI demos](http://semantic-ui.com/) and couldn't find a Semantic UI equivalent to [Bootstrap Popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).  These are popups that usually open connected to their toggle and can stay open for the user to interact with.

If no popovers exist in Semantic UI, what design / element do people recommend to use instead?  The basic idea is to get something that works like the "Add new metric" button [in this design](http://pauginer.github.io/prototypes/analytics-dashboard/index.html).

Comment: If you look at the [Popover Examples](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/examples) there is a trigger-imitated popup. This works fairly the same as a Bootstrap popover.

Comment: awesome, thanks!  I missed this because I only looked at the "Definition" tab.  Good general tip for browsing their docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Aibrean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3739498/aibrean) said, there is already such a functionality, see [Semantic Popup](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html) module.

```html
<div class="ui button" data-title="Lorem ipsum" data-content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." data-position="right center">Click Me</div>

<div class="ui button" data-html="<div class='ui secondary vertical pointing menu'><a class='active item' href='#'>Home</a><a class='item' href='#'>Messages</a><a class='item' href='#'>Friends</a></div>">Click here</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.button').popup({
    on: 'click',
    closable: false
});
</script>
```

Here is working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0q42ztp1/

Answer (score 1):

Semantic UI has popover tips now. Probably didn't exist when this question was asked, but it is pretty robust and similar to what bootstrap achieves.

https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html

Comment: Oh thanks for commenting!  I ended up using a different library.  But semantic doesn't look maintained anymore, we were looking at migrating to Vuetify or something in-house.